# Each time the result of XGBoost is different

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I'm running xgboost and I fix the seed number 
but the result is different for each time when I rerun the xgboost with same dataset

```
xgb = XGBClassifier(
     bagging_fraction= 0.8,
     boosting= 'gbdt',
    colsample_bytree= 0.7,
    feature_fraction= 0.9,
    learning_rate= 0.05,
    max_bin= 32,
    max_depth= 10,
    min_child_weight= 11,
    missing= -999,
    n_estimators= 400,
    nthread= 4,
    num_leaves= 100,
    predictor= 'gpu_predictor',
    seed= 1000,
    silent= 1,
    subsample= 0.8,
    tree_method= 'gpu_hist',
    verbose= True
)
```

This is my parameter and

```
# Our data is already scaled we should split our training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# This is explicitly used for undersampling.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
# partially based on https://www.kaggle.com/c0conuts/xgb-k-folds-fastai-pca
predicts = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train, y_train):
    print("###")
    X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_val = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_val, y_val)], 
            early_stopping_rounds=30)
    predicts.append(xgb.predict(X_test))
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem as the OP described above. I got different results running `xgboost()` even when setting `set.seed(12345)` in R. I kept all the other parameters the same (`nrounds`, `max_depth`, `eta`, `alpha`, `booster='dart'`, `subsample=0.8`). Does anyone know how to overcome this randomness issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some seeds there:

- Numpy
- Pandas
- StratifiedKFold

I will say that StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True) without a seed can make your results change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both a fixed random state in the train_test_split and in the initialization of the classifier. Your random_state in the train_test_split is there, however you missed the random_state in the initialization of the XGBClassifier. Add it there and it should be working as expected.

```
xgb = XGBClassifier(
 bagging_fraction= 0.8,
 boosting= 'gbdt',
colsample_bytree= 0.7,
feature_fraction= 0.9,
learning_rate= 0.05,
max_bin= 32,
max_depth= 10,
min_child_weight= 11,
missing= -999,
n_estimators= 400,
nthread= 4,
num_leaves= 100,
predictor= 'gpu_predictor',
seed= 1000,
silent= 1,
subsample= 0.8,
tree_method= 'gpu_hist',
verbose= True
random_state = 42
)
```